# Error on Row add in UltraGrid Infragistics

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm getting this error when try to add the row in UltraGrid

> Not enough context to add a new row. Either a row in this band or the
>   parent band has to be active to provide for enough context.

To add new rows I'm using following code line. But giving error. `myGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).AddNew()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the grid empty (or without a DataSource set) when you call AddNew?

Comment: yeah it is empty and there is no datasource.

Comment: And how do you suppose the grid will be able to create a row if it doesn't know what columns are to be displayed?

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: I have defined the columns in the code only.

Comment: Please show all the relevant part of your code. How do you define the columns? In which point you call the AddNew method? Ehm, yep We need more context :-)

Answer (score 3):

In order to add `UltraGrid` rows at runtime, the data source property of the `UltraGrid` has to be different than null. This way the data source context is familiar to the `UltraGrid` and it adds a new row based on the already provided data schema. Otherwise the `UltraGrid` has no idea what the new row should look like. More information at the following documentation page -  [Add Rows to WinGrid Programmatically](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/WinGrid_Add_Rows_to_WinGrid_Programmatically.html)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Create a table that will contain three columns
    Dim table As New DataTable("Table")

    ' Create three columns that will hold sample data
    Dim column1 As New DataColumn("Column 1", GetType(String))
    Dim column2 As New DataColumn("Column 2", GetType(Integer))
    Dim column3 As New DataColumn("Column 3", GetType(System.Drawing.Color))

    ' Add the three columns to the table.
    table.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {column1, column2, column3})

    ' Assign grid's data soure to the newly created table
    Me.ultraGrid1.DataSource = table
End Sub

Private Sub ultraButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Now this line of code works! 
    Me.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).AddNew()
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you would like to define the data schema at design time, you can utilize from the `UltraDataSource` component and `UltraGrid` designer.

[image]